# Sharing cookies between background page and Safari in new-way extensions

Tags: cookies, safari-extension

Trying to update my old-styled Safari extension with background HTML page according to `native app` extension. The extension should perform HTTP requests in a background mode, and the earlier version used the same cookies that Safari did. But after migrating to `native` code, `NSURLSessionDataTask` can't access cookies that Safari has anymore.

Can anyone suggest how can I manage this case? Unfortunately, I can't pass cookies via messages to 'native' code (they are `httponly`).